# Is there a better way to generate a random password?

Tags: python

```
pass1_1 = random.choice([random.choice(alphabet)+random.choice(numbers)])
pass1_2 = random.choice([random.choice(alphabet)+random.choice(numbers)])
pass1_3 = random.choice([random.choice(alphabet)+random.choice(numbers)])
pass1_4 = random.choice([random.choice(alphabet)+random.choice(numbers)])
pass1_5 = random.choice([random.choice(alphabet)+random.choice(numbers)])
pass1_6 = random.choice([random.choice(alphabet)+random.choice(numbers)])
pass1 = pass1_1+pass1_2+pass1_3+pass1_4+pass1_5+pass1_6
print(pass1)
```

Its python,
Alphabet, number and sc are list made

Comment: I think this question fits more on [Code Review Stack](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: `[random.choice(alphabet) + random.choice(numbers)]` is a list of 1, what are you randomizing there?

Comment: Its is a random password generator

Answer (score 1):

sure, this is just a loop:

```
password = "".join(random.choice(alphabet+numbers) for _ in range(6))
```

Explanation:

`alphabet+numbers` creates a new string (or list if they are lists) "abc..012"

`random.choice` picks a random one

the for repeats it for 6 times

the join put them back together

in multiple lines:

```
password = ""
chars = alphabet+numbers
for _ in range(6):
   password += random.choice(chars)
```

Comment: better use `pass_` as a variable name if you want to use that reserved name